# Use jQuery UI .sortable's serialize method to get the html of sorted elements as values

Tags: jquery, inline, jquery-ui-sortable, editing

I use PHP but Jquery is the problem I have with. Can't find the answers after a long search. My knowledge of Ajax, Jquery is limited. This is just a test script, if it works I can implement it in the project.

Goal : To change order of a list with autosave - but still editable with autosave.

What works : Change order (no autosave), inline editing works with autosave but *without* the script of "sortable list" !

Problem : when left click on a list element (li), it's draggable to its new position but inline editing doesn't work anymore !

Questions : How to resolve problem above ?
            What data will be giving through the $.post link for the new order positions ? (I need the element-ID and the ID from the new order). Will both be giving through the link ? Each

has an ID which are needed, not the ID from the DIV are needed.

Probable solution : to make a handle to drag the element so that the rest of the list element is editable OR just correction of the codes.

Every little step is a step to the grand solution. Who will help me ?

Generated HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
    function showEdit(editableObj) {
        $(editableObj).css("background","#FFF");
    } 

    function saveToDatabase(editableObj,column,id) {
        $(editableObj).css("background","#FFF url(loaderIcon.gif) no-repeat right");
        $.ajax({
            url: "saveedit.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:'column='+column+'&editval='+editableObj.innerHTML+'&id='+id,
            success: function(data){
                $(editableObj).css("background","#FDFDFD");
            }        
       });
    }
    </script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="inc_link_jquery-1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inc_link_jquery-ui-1.js"></script>  

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){                  
    $(function() {
        $("#listorder ul").sortable({ opacity: 0.6, cursor: 'move', update: function() {
            var order = $(this).sortable("serialize") + '&action=orderlist'; 
                $.post("saveedit2.php", order); 
        }                                 
        });
    });
}); 
</script>   

</head>
<body>      
<br><br><br>

<div id="listorder">
<ul class="ui-sortable">
<li id=1><div contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'question','1')" onClick="showEdit(this);">question 3</div>
<div contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'answer','1')" onClick="showEdit(this);">answer 3<br></div></li>

<li id=2><div contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'question','2')" onClick="showEdit(this);">question 1</div>
<div contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'answer','2')" onClick="showEdit(this);">answer 1<br></div></li>

<li id=3><div contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'question','3')" onClick="showEdit(this);">question 2</div>
<div contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'answer','3')" onClick="showEdit(this);">answer 2<br></div></li>

</ul>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since your issue is not related to php, you should lose the php in your question and instead show us the generated html

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the ids for your sortable lis must be formatted a specific way and you cannout populate the values from the html of the sorted item. The value must be *in the `id` attribute*.:

[From the docs:](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/)

> serialize( options )Returns: String
>
> Serializes the sortable's item **ids** into a form/ajax submittable string. Calling this method produces a hash that can be appended to any url to easily submit a new item order back to the server.
>
> It works by default by looking at the id of each item in the format "setname_number" *("key_value" might have been more apt here IMHO)*, and it spits out a hash like "setname[]=number&setname[]=number".
>
> **Note: If serialize returns an empty string, make sure the id attributes include an underscore. They must be in the form: "set_number"**
>
> For example, a 3 element list with id attributes "foo_1", "foo_5", "foo_2" will serialize to "foo[]=1&foo[]=5&foo[]=2".
>
> You can use an underscore, equal sign or hyphen to separate the set and number. For example "foo=1", "foo-1", and "foo_1" all serialize to "foo[]=1".

#### NOTE:

That said, `.sortable("serialize")` really only works if you have a number or a small amount of text that is already known.

**Here is an example of how `sortable("serialize")` works:**

```js
$(".sortableList").sortable({
  scroll: true,
  axis: "y",
  containment: "parent",
  handle: $("div.sortableListTitleText").add("div.handle.move"),
  update: function() {
    var newList = $(".sortableList").sortable("serialize", {
      attribute: "itemid"
    });
  }
});

$("#listorder ul").sortable({
  opacity: 0.6,
  cursor: 'move',
  update: function(event, ui) {
    var incorrect = $(this).sortable("serialize");
    var correct = $(this).sortable("serialize",{attribute: "innerHTML"}); 
    console.log(incorrect);
    console.log(correct);
    
  }
});


function showEdit(editableObj) { 
  //....
}

function saveToDatabase(editableObj, column, id) { 
  //....
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="listorder">
  <ul class="ui-sortable">
    <li id="foo_1">
      <div contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'question','1')" onClick="showEdit(this);">question 3</div>
      <div contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'answer','1')" onClick="showEdit(this);">answer 3
        <br>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li id="foo_d">
      <div contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'question','2')" onClick="showEdit(this);">question 1</div>
      <div contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'answer','2')" onClick="showEdit(this);">answer 1
        <br>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li id="foo_5">
      <div contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'question','3')" onClick="showEdit(this);">question 2</div>
      <div contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'answer','3')" onClick="showEdit(this);">answer 2
        <br>
      </div>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Since you are using contenteditable divs that are dynamic and may contain any characters like `= - _` and html, I would suggest that you dont use `.sortable("serialize")` at all and instea loop over the elements in the sortable list and manually set a key and value pair for each element then send that string in your ajax.

#### Here is how I would do this:

```js
$("#listorder ul").sortable({
  opacity: 0.6,
  cursor: 'move',
  update: function(event, ui) {
       var params=['action=orderlist'];
      $(this).find(".ui-sortable-handle").each(function () {
            var $this=$(this);
            var key=$this.attr('id');
            var value=encodeURIComponent($this.html());  // you MUST encode this val since it may have chars thatll muck up the string
            var param = key+'='+value;
            params.push(param); 
      });
      var paramsString=params.join('')
      console.log(paramsString);
    
    
     $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "page.php",
     data: paramsString,
     success: function(response) { 
      
     },
     error: function(xhr, status, error) { 
     }
     });
    
  }
});


function showEdit(editableObj) { 
  //....
}

function saveToDatabase(editableObj, column, id) { 
  //....
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="listorder">
  <ul class="ui-sortable">
    <li id="foo_1">
      <div contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'question','1')" onClick="showEdit(this);">question 3</div>
      <div contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'answer','1')" onClick="showEdit(this);">answer 3
        <br>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li id="foo_2">
      <div contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'question','2')" onClick="showEdit(this);">question 1</div>
      <div contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'answer','2')" onClick="showEdit(this);">answer 1
        <br>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li id="foo_3">
      <div contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'question','3')" onClick="showEdit(this);">question 2</div>
      <div contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'answer','3')" onClick="showEdit(this);">answer 2
        <br>
      </div>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I only need the ID from the <LI> .  
The <LI> does have an ID, the div's are moving along because they are within the <LI>.

Comment: See my update, I misspoke. But your ids are not formatted correctly to yes serialize. The ids must contain the key and the **value** to be serialized. See the example from the docs above.

Comment: @FreeSpirit I added an example, now do you see what I mean?

Comment: Actually, I don't see it. It's to difficult for me.  I tried your code and it moves but it shows as a second list in one of the 'main' list (LI).
I can edit them but the color that shows after I clicked for editing stays no matter what.

Comment: So if I click in every element of the list,  it stays colored. 
Also I don't know what that console.log(paramsString); means, was this for your test ?   But where do I need to put the $.post(...); than ?   I see in you code that you encode the string so I suppose that this is meant for the $.post(...);  Right ?

Comment: I forgot to fix the id on the last one, Updated. The bottom line is that `sortable. serialize()` is not meant for this useage. Lets say you want to pass the key value pair `myDatabaseId=5`, to do this, you would make the li's `id` `id="myDatabaseId_5"`. This is really meant to allow you track the order of your elements. You can technically send text like `myName=John` by doing `id="myNam_John"` but you cant make it pass html like you want.

Comment: Im not sure why there were two calls to `sortable` in my example, I must have pasted that there by mistake.

Comment: @FreeSpirit Updated the example to show how to use the paramString in the ajax call. The console.log is just there to show you the compiled value, you can remove.

Comment: Thank you for all the effort you've put into this. I got a strange problem. When I test the code here on this page, I can order the list to a new position. But when I test it on my pc (with the latest wamp installed) when I change the order of the list "question 1"  to position of "question 3", Its position would normally be changed BUT instead it settles itself within the <LI> of  "question 3"  and the html data <div><ul>... of the "question 1" is saved in the DB of "question 3".  I followed your example here but still my script acts different than the script on this page. Any idea why ?

Comment: @FreeSpirit are you sure you are not calling `.sortable()` multiple times or something like that?

Comment: No, I copied your code and reused the code for function saveToDatabase(editableObj,column,id) and function showEdit(editableObj). I skipped a few windows updates, any to do with this ?   I use the latest firefox and it become more crazy, I can not drag the list in a new position in I.E.11.